# Calculating mean of column based on the occurence of a number in another column Pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I've got a Pandas dataframe like the one below. What I'm trying to do is calculating the mean of column s2, for every time that '5' occures in s1.

```
s1  s2
5   0.5
1   0.43
5   1
5   1
```

In this case, 5 occures three times, so we take the average over 0.5+1+1=0.83.
Can someone help me to calculate this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df[df['s1']==5]['s2'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mean = df.loc[df['s1'] == 5, 's2'].mean()
```

output:

```
0.8333333333333334
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the breakup of answers above, try this -

```
import pandas as pd
  
data = [[5, 0.5], [1, .43], [5, 1], [5, 1]]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['S1', 'S2'])

df = df.loc[df['S1'] == 5]

df["S2"].mean()
```