# Calculating mean of columns based on the occurence of a number in other columns Pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, conditional-statements

This question is based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70203328/calculating-mean-of-column-based-on-the-occurence-of-a-number-in-another-column).

I've got a Pandas dataframe like the one below. What I'm trying to do is calculating the mean of column r1 till r50, for every time that '5' occurs in the respective s-column (r1-s2, r2-s2,... r50-s50).

```
s1  ... s50 r1 ... r50
5       5  0.5    1
1       5  0.43   0.5
5       1  1      0.43
5       5  1      1
```

In this case, in s1: 5 occures three times, so we take the average over 0.5+1+1=0.83, in s50: 5 occures three times, so we take the average over 1+0.5+1=0.83. I want to get the result in a new data frame. Can someone help me to calculate this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for columns starting with `s`, and for each column, select indexes where the item is `5`, and select those rows from the column of the same name except with `s` replaced by `r`, and compute the [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html):

```
s = df.filter(like='s').apply(lambda col: df.loc[col == 5, col.name.replace('s', 'r')].mean())
```

Output:

```
>>> s
s1     0.833333
s50    0.833333
dtype: float64

>>> s['s1']
0.8333333333333334
```